# Realtime Table Updates

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-4

I am trying to figure out how to update a table real time.

Ex.
Table 1 has employee name, employee id, has work (check box)
| pulls data from database. Checked goes to table 2 |

Table 2 has employee name, employee id, has work (checked, checked box)
| When checked by table 1, update/insert into another table in the database. And get placed here. |

So table 1 has a list of employees and if I mark them saying they have work (checked) they would go from that table to the other table, (real time).

BTW, there would be more tables like Table 1 but only 1 table 2. And all this would be on 1 page. IDK if this matters but I am using Laravel 4 framework.

So my thoughts was maybe ajax?

If anyone has some example code that I could learn from, I would love that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this Java or JavaScript related? Also, are you using PHP?

Comment: Sorry, I updated it.

Comment: Have a look at jQuery's $.ajax method to send data to your laravel resource after change of the input field

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery DataTables plugin, its easy to implement and you only send the data using json

http://www.datatables.net/

----- EDIT -----

Its just an example, it creates a checkbox and then you can use jquery to detect the checked event and send another ajax to update the server and/or update the second table

```
$(function () {
    $('#table').DataTable(
            {
                "ajax": {
                    "url": URL_DIR + "ajax/" + extradata,
                    "type": "POST",
                },
                "columnDefs": [
                    {"targets": [-1],
                        "defaultContent": '<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="test" class="ajax">',
                        "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                            $(td).children('input').attr('data-id', rowData[0]);
                        }},
                ],
            }
    )
    $('body').on('click', 'checkbox.ajax', function () {
        alert('click');
    });
})
```

Comment: I am using DataTables but my thing is, if I check the box (has work) how would it save to the database and the Table 2 update on the same page?

Comment: Just edited the answer, it adds a checkbox to the table

Comment: here is my blade template [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/8NGZPT7x) I want to click has work under the available and it moves to has work.

I cant seem to get this after all the input everyone has said. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a framework like Ember or Angular or Knockout or Backbone or ?. These Javascript frameworks would connect, via AJAX, to the API and allow for a UI.

If it is a small project, you could use jQuery to handle the AJAX requests; no large framework necessary.

Comment: I was looking at AngularJS because it's realtime(onepage) but wasn't sure if that would be the best option to do this. But might be the only choice.

Comment: Just to verify here, you realize that although it is AJAX and handled client side, it is not more "real-time" than if the application was built in PHP. The AJAX requests will only occur when a change has been made, so in theory if you had multiple editors in there at once, they won't necessarily immediately see each others changes.